# Run Jquery method when enter key is pressed

Tags: jquery, lightbox, keypress

I'm trying to run a method when the enter key has been pressed. This method is already being used by a button. Basically, when the user fills in a text field and clicks a submit button they get a lightbox. What I want to do is run this same action, but when the enter key has been pressed. Ive looked into using .keypress but I can only find examples where the form tag is a standard html form tag and not a asp.net form tag. I think at the moment the form is responding only to the .net controls on the page and I cant override this with the jquery method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind a `keypress` event to the document and `trigger()` the handler on your button.

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(e){
   if(e.which === 13) { // return
      $('#buttonid').trigger('click');
   }
});
```

This would fire whenever you press the return key on your site. You probably want it only to happen if someone uses `return` in your input form. You would just need to change the `selector` from `document` to any kind of selector that matches your control.

Ref.: [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Dang, Andy, I feel like I'm racing you all the time.  When do you sleep? =)

Comment: @mkoistinen: I've never heard about that, tell me more about that "sleep" thingy :p

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
   // test for the enter key
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      // Do your function
      myFunction();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".input_loginform").keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("User pressed 'Enter' in a text input. sender form #"+this.form.id);
        postlogin("#"+this.form.id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ENTER_KEY = 13;
var user_key;
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
  user_key = e.keyCode || e.which
   if(user_key === ENTER_KEY) { 
      document.querySelector("#button").click();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button" onclick="console.log('button pressed')">button</button>
```