# How do I write a keyup function

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run Jquery method when enter key is press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716574/run-jquery-method-when-enter-key-is-press)

I am trying to write a function that when the user presses the enter key it does the same thing as the code below:

```
$('#switch-fighter-search-button-link').click(function(){
  window.location=$(this).attr("href")+$('#switch-fighter-text').val();
  return false;
});
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Your title mentions "keyup", but your question is tagged "onkeydown".  Do you have a preference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (I am assuming you are using jQuery based on the question contents):

```
       $(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {
            if (objEvent.keyCode == 13) { //enter is pressed
                $('#switch-fighter-search-button-link').click();
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#input_text').keyup(function(e) {
    //alert(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('Enter key was pressed.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#switch-fighter-search-button-link').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.which==13){
            // call your function
    }
});
```

in jQuery e.which will get the ASCII code of the character in a cross-browser method (vs. having to do that yourself).